# COGO rotation skewed, likely coordinate issue?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, cogo

I am COGO'ing a survey plan from June of 1972, the scan of the paper plan is not so great and does not list any Datum or declination used, but only a scale bar showing measurements are in feet, and the coordinates are DD.MM.SS

I entered a ground correction to get my feet into meters, and when COGO'ing it I wind up with a shape which closely aligns to what the cadaster says it should look like, but is obviously rotated SW.  I suspected this is to do with some coordinate system mismatch so wondering for some advice.

I believe in 1972 there was a new variant of WGS that came out, so not sure if the plan might be in either WGS1966 or WGS1972, but can't even guarantee it is in WGS, only making a guess based on the DD.MM.SS coordinates, but for all I know this is using NAD27...

Below is a picture of the COGO (green line) and where it sits with the cadaster, the POC is the NW corner and I had to COGO two lines in each direction as the area where they would close the traverse is indecipherable on the paper scan.

[image]

To complicate things, the POC for the traverse on the paper scan is very hard to read, but putting in the rough coordinates I can read doesn't put me near the shape in question, instead it puts me several kilometers away in the middle of water, not on land, but I figure the POC could be a key to sorting out the Datum for the rest of it and if I can figure out how to make those coordinates fall somewhere close to the COGO'd shape I'll be on the right track.  Here's a pic of the POC:

[image]

Any advice on how to correct for this unknown coordinate system and make this COGO shape line up?

Should I be adjusting all bearings with declination from june 1972?

Comment: If you create a Traverse file, you can rerun the cogo commands using different "Direction offset" angles to figure out the best Direction offset.
Editor, Options, Units, Ground to Grid Correction, Direction Offset

Comment: It's very unlikely to be in WGS72 or WGS66. NAD27 is more likely. Astronomic / geodetic bearings should be pretty close. It looks like you're off more than that. It's also possible that there's a mistake in the description and the online data is corrected.